# Android show crouton layout below Toolbar

Tags: android

I want to use [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) on below toolbar by this code which documented on library site:

```
Crouton.makeText(activity, "MY TEXT", Style.ALERT, toolbar).show();
```

its show top of my `Toolbar` and i can't change position of that, please help me, Thanks

[image]

My Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.pishguy.androidapplication.cafemaku.Views.Activities.ActivityRegister.RegisterViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/root_layout">

        <include layout="@layout/application_toolbar"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/user_registered_mobile_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_register_edit_box_style"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@{viewModel.hint}"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black_35"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:inputType="phone"/>

            <com.pishguy.androidapplication.cafemaku.Libraries.CircularProgressButton.dd.CircularProgressButton
                android:id="@+id/continue_register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_blue_buttons"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{viewModel.onRegisterAccount}"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:cpb_cornerRadius="25dp"
                app:cpb_textComplete="@string/complete_register"
                app:cpb_textError="@string/error_register"
                app:cpb_textIdle="@string/continue_register"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and my toolbar layout is :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:titleTextColor="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.pishguy.androidapplication.cafemaku.Widgets.FontAwesome
                android:id="@+id/icon_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:shadowColor="#22000000"
                android:shadowDx="3"
                android:shadowDy="3"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:text="&#xf002;"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `FrameLayout`;

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_crouton_anchor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

below your toolbar and use it as ViewGroup in `Crouton makeText(Activity activity, int textResourceId, Style style, ViewGroup viewGroup)`